# Getting "SQLExpress database file auto-creation error" for site that uses AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, but connection string is to SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, provider

I have an `ASP.NET v2.0` website (not web application) where the root directory is public, but the "Admin" subdirectory requires authentication.  Everything about the setup is very generic - I used a connection string defined in the root web.config, and the standard `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` provider, and I'm using the ASP.NET Login control.
The web.config in the Admin directory specifies that the user must have the "Admin" role.

I'm using `SQL Server 2008`, and my connection string is good; every root level page is data driven and they all work fine.
Provider configuration seems goo.

when I log in, the Login control's "`OnLoggedIn`" event fires.
The last line in that event code redirects me down to my `Admin/Default.aspx` page.  My breakpoint in "OnLoggedIn" shows me that all's well until the redirect down into my Admin directory...and then...

...and then I wait...and wait...

And then I get an error telling me it's experienced a "`SQLExpress database file auto-creation error`."

Why in the world is it suddenly trying to create a SQL Server Express file?  Why is it suddenly ignoring my connection string?

One odd clue: Just before the last line of the "OnLoggedIn" event I put in this:

```
bool blnTest = User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

I wanted to see if `blnTest = true`.
What happens is the process hits this line...and waits...and eventually tells me it can't access the SQL Server Express database.  It seems that any reference (either in my code, or behind the scenes) to determine the User's Role, calls the wrong database.

EDIT:  Argh, *sometimes* it waits when I test blnTest.  Other times it immediately reports the value as "false."

Comment: What is the connection string for your RoleProvider?  Is it the same as your AuthenticationProvider?

Comment: That part of the web.config is simply this...
<roleManager enabled="true" />

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to your comment, it looks like you have haven't explicitly configured a role provider for you site.

If all that's in your web.config is:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

Then you are relying on the default providers declared further up the configuration hieracrchy (machine.config, global web.config, etc)

In machine.config you've probably got something like:

```
<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
      applicationName="/" 
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
      applicationName="/" 
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

As you can see, the first provider is configured to use a connectionString called LocalSqlServer - which is also usually declared in the machine.config:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And this is designed to use a local file based database that will be created if it doesn't already exist.

So to get roles working on your site, you should ammend your root web.config to something like:

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
      connectionStringName="YourConnectionStringName" 
      applicationName="/" 
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Using the <clear /> element will remove all previously defined providers for that type.

Comment: Thanks, I know this question is very old but it was also a great help to me. One question, I know have `<providers>` within both my `<roleManager>` and `<membership>` sections. Seems like they contain the same information. Does anyone know why I need both?

Comment: Because you can have different ones (for example you might want a custom role provider that supports inherited roles, while you're happy with the default membership provider). On top of that if you look closely you'll see they are different: one adds the sql**membership**provider, while the other adds the sql**role**provider.

Comment: It's helpful to know that the <roleManager> config belongs inside the <system.web> element in your site's web.config

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the `AttachDBFilename` option in the connection string you are in fact asking for your-very-own-just-in-time-provisioned SQL Server instance, aka the 'user instance'. This instance is created by asking the 'master' instance (the .\SQLEXPRESS instance) to provision a child instance, which implies copying the master/model/msdb into your profile, starting a new SQL Server process under your account configured to use the freshly copied master/model/msdb, then asking this 'child' instance to attach the specified 'file' as a new database. The details are explained in [SQL Server 2005 Express Edition User Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564(SQL.90).aspx).

The process of creating a child instance is extremly fragile and when it breaks the DB call results eventually in a time out error when opening the connection. In your case it seems that the process breaks in some cases (when you reach the protected part of the site). Why it breaks, is very hard to guess without proper information. Look at the **Common Issues** in the linked article and see if any applies to you. Also check the system event log for any message why the child instances cannot start or it cannot open the MDF file. Note that a common mistake is to ask for the same physical file with AttachDBFilename under different credentials: each credential will start its own 'child' instance and only the first one will succeed in attaching the desired database.

Comment: As I said, I'm using SQL Server 2008, not an MDF file.  My connection string does not have AttachDBFilename in it.

Data Source=MYSERVER;Initial Catalog=WebsiteDB;User Id=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword;

Comment: Zhaph already explained why the LocalSqlServer is used (ie. Express user instance)

Comment: Only because I had all the details from the comments ;)

Comment: Thanks Zhaph, yes, you nailed it and reminded me to keep the machine.config in mind.  

And Remus, regarding the comment that Zhaph "already" explained the Express issue, the order of the comments were: my original post, Nick's question about RoleProviders, my answer to Nick, your mention of Express, and then Zhaph's winning answer.  I wasn't trying to get Express to work, I was trying to avoid it altogether.

Comment: @Tom: sry Tom, I did not mean 'already' to be derogatory in any way. I just meant that I can keep my comment short and not enter into details.

Comment: @Tom hehe - YOU might be using SQL Server, but ASP.NET already made plans!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was due to the services for sql server being disabled.

Check under services.msc to see if the sqlexpress service is running. If it is check to see if you have sql express installed on your machine