# MVC 5 Asp.Net Identity Authorize Attribute error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I migrated my MVC application to ASP.Net Identity 2.0 from SimpleMembership and remove all reference of latter from application.

But whenever I use the authorize attribute in my controller, I come across the **SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:** . (BTW, I'm using Ms SQL 2012, and all other functionality is working well with EF)

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult UserList()
    {
        var users = db.AspNetUsers.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

I have tried all the following and still clueless on where am getting it wrong :

1. Ensure no reference of SimpleMembership anyway in my app and web.config. I even removed the WebMatrix references.
2. Added   *filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute())* in my startup.
3. Added following in start up

   ```
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
       app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
       app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

       // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
       app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
       {
           AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
           LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
       });

       // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
       app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
   ```
4. **Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled** not found in my context. So meaning lazy loading is enabled by default.
5. Added following in my login code :

   ```
       AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
   ClaimsIdentity identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
   AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
   {
       IsPersistent = isPersistent
   }, identity);
   ```
6. Yes - the role exists in correct case.

Comment: Do you consistently get this error or are there times when things work as expected?

Comment: Might there be anything in web.config that is tying in SimpleMembership? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402430/getting-sqlexpress-database-file-auto-creation-error-for-asp-net-site-that-use

Comment: Consistently getting it. Web.config is free of any kind of membership reference.